# Authentication and session management in iOS

Tags: ios, authentication, core-data, ios5, plist

Whats the recommended way for storing authentication information in iOS that could be easily fetched from anywhere in the application, is it the Core Data framework or plist or anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plist data can be easily accessed.

Safer way is to store the data in NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 2):

NSUserDefaults also stores information in the form of a plist. Storing authentication information in keychain is more meaningful than NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the iOS Keychain just like on the mac NSUserDefaults isn't secure
see

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GenericKeychain/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007797-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2